# Flexbox formatting issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I'm attempting to use flexbox to create a box, with three smaller boxes inside.

The below code works for laptop larger screen displays, however, when reviewed under a mobile screen the third box appears to be smaller in width. I've checked my code, but I'm not seeing what I've done to cause this issue. Therefore I'm not sure if in fact this is a flex box issue?

From the second screenshot, you will also see that when viewed under Firefox, formatting becomes poorer. I'm struggling reseraching to see if this is a FF or flexbox issue.

```
[wpv-layout-start]
    [wpv-items-found]
<div class="row flexbox-wrap">
    <!-- wpv-loop-start -->
    <wpv-loop>
      <div class="col-sm-4 flexbox-equalise">
        <article class="well well-equal">
          <h4>[wpv-post-title]</h4>
          <p>[wpv-post-excerpt output="raw"]</p>
          <p class="lead">[wpv-woo-product-price]</p>
          <div class="well-actions [wpv-post-slug]">
            [wpv-woo-buy-or-select add_to_cart_text="Join now!" class="btn-block"]
          </div>

        </article>
      </div>
    </wpv-loop>
    <!-- wpv-loop-end -->
</div>
    [/wpv-items-found]
    [wpv-no-items-found]
        <strong>[wpml-string context="wpv-views"]No items found[/wpml-string]</strong>
    [/wpv-no-items-found]
[wpv-layout-end]
```

CSS STYLES

```
/* The following code formats the modal box subscription results for services that can be selected after the Join Now button is pressed. This information is seen on the join now auth page as well as the signup page, its controlled by this toolset view, with the custom code above to pull back the results. */

.flexbox-equalise .well { position: relative; padding-bottom: 76px; }
.flexbox-equalise .well .well-actions {position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; text-align: -webkit-center; padding-bottom: 10px;}

.well-actions.school-nursery-plan {background-color: #fdd731; margin-top: 22px !important; padding-top: 12px;}
.well-actions.standard-yearly-plan {background-color: #db2230; margin-top: 22px !important; padding-top: 12px;}
.well-actions.standard-monthly-plan {background-color: #1e76b7; margin-top: 22px !important; padding-top: 12px;}
```

[image: Chrome mobile view]

[image: FireFox]

Comment: If you resize the browser window on the computer, so page goes into _mobile layout_, and right click on the "Monthly plan" element, you can in the popup choose "Inspect" (or similar). From there you will be able to see the elements and their properties/layout, and can read out what goes wrong. You will also be able to grab both HTML and CSS, to create a code snippet you can share with us, reproducing the issue, and make it easier for us to help.

Comment: I think it's because the third box does not have a full line of text, as all the other boxes do, so it is only wide enough to fit the text. width: 100% ??

Answer (score 0):

```css
width: 100%
```

The text in the 3rd box isn't as wide as in the others, so you have to let the browser know you want it to fit the full size of the screen and not fit the text size